# XSLT - Xpath comparing attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

can any one explain me the difference between

```
<xsl:template match="a/@ref[.='attr']">
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="a[@ref='attr']">
```

is this template matches the same thing or different thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first template is selecting the attribute `ref`.

The second template is selecting the element `a`.

Both have a predicate that requires the attribute `ref` to equal `attr`.